# FileSystemObject: Retrieving folder name from UNC path

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I don't know how to **get the name of a folder** in a **UNC path** with the `FileSystemObject` object. For example:
From "`\\Server\FolderA`" I would like to be able to get "`FolderA`". The method I was hoping would work is "`GetBaseName`" but it doesn't seem to work when the "`IsRootFolder`" property is True.

The following procedure:

```
Public Sub GetUNCFolderName()

    Const stPathA As String = "\\Server\FolderA"
    Const stPathB As String = "\\Server\FolderA\FolderB"

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Debug.Print "---------"
    Debug.Print "Path A: " & stPathA
    Debug.Print "GetAbsolutePathName: " & fso.GetAbsolutePathName(stPathA)
    Debug.Print "GetBaseName        : " & fso.GetBaseName(stPathA)
    Debug.Print "IsRootFolder       : " & fso.GetFolder(stPathA).IsRootFolder
    
    Debug.Print "---------"
    Debug.Print "Path B: " & stPathB
    Debug.Print "GetAbsolutePathName: " & fso.GetAbsolutePathName(stPathB)
    Debug.Print "GetBaseName        : " & fso.GetBaseName(stPathB)
    Debug.Print "IsRootFolder       : " & fso.GetFolder(stPathB).IsRootFolder

End Sub
```

Returns this result:

```
---------
Path A: \\Server\FolderA
GetAbsolutePathName: \\Server\FolderA
GetBaseName        : 
IsRootFolder       : True
---------
Path B: \\Server\FolderA\FolderB
GetAbsolutePathName: \\Server\FolderA\FolderB
GetBaseName        : FolderB
IsRootFolder       : False
```

As you can see "`fso.GetBaseName(stPathA)`" returns an empty string and "fso.GetBaseName(stPathB)" does not.

I appreciate any ideas you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried `fso.GetFolder(pathhere).Name` ?

Comment: May be `FolderA` in your example is not 'folder' but 'share name'

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, it returns an empty string

Comment: @4dmonster: It is a shared folder (with the same folder name) on my local drive with all privileges granted to everyone

Comment: @David when you look from local computer - yes it is folder. When you look from network - no, it is share name. If you check `fso.GetFolder(stPathA).Drive` you will get `\\Server\FolderA`. As i understand it is SMB protocol feature.

Comment: @4dmonster Thank you. I didn't know the terminology

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the best solution but I haven't been able to find one using only the FileSystemObject object. At least it's a lap that saves the problem. My solution goes through adding an if statement: `If (fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(PathA)).DriveType = Network) And fso.GetFolder(PathA).IsRootFolder Then`

```
Public Sub GetUNCFolderName()

    Dim PathA As String, PathB As String
    PathA = "\\Server\FolderA"
    PathB = "\\Server\FolderA\FolderB"
    Const Network = 3

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If (fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(PathA)).DriveType = Network) And fso.GetFolder(PathA).IsRootFolder Then
        If VBA.Right$(PathA, 1) = "\" Then PathA = VBA.Left$(PathA, Len(PathA) - 1)
        Debug.Print "PathA-1: " & VBA.Mid$(PathA, InStrRev(PathA, "\") + 1)
    Else
        Debug.Print "PathA-2: " & fso.GetBaseName(PathA)
    End If
    
    If (fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(PathB)).DriveType = Network) And fso.GetFolder(PathB).IsRootFolder Then
        If VBA.Right$(PathB, 1) = "\" Then PathB = VBA.Left$(PathB, Len(PathB) - 1)
        Debug.Print "PathB-1: " & VBA.Mid$(PathB, InStrRev(PathB, "\") + 1)
    Else
        Debug.Print "PathB-2: " & fso.GetBaseName(PathB)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Returns

```
PathA-1: FolderA
PathB-2: FolderB
```